# Join 2 tables resulting in multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have 2 (mysql) tables:

```
orders:
   order_number

deliveries:
   id, order_number, status
```

Orders can have multiple deliveries in the deliveries table.  Right now I query for 50 orders, then loop them (php) and query the deliveries table for deliveries where order_number = orders.order_number and merge the arrays.

Ideally this is one query, not 51.  I've tried 100 combinations of joins and groups but can't crack this seemingly simple query.  Result should be:

```
[orders] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [order_number] => 16021322220558
                [deliveries] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 13332
                                [order_number] => 16021322220558
                                [status] => delivering
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 13333
                                [order_number] => 16021322220558
                                [status] => delivering
                            )
                    )

            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [order_number] => 16021322220559
                [deliveries] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 13334
                                [order_number] => 16021322220559
                                [status] => delivering
                            )
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 13335
                                [order_number] => 16021322220559
                                [status] => delivering
                            )
                    )

            )
        ...
    )
```

**Edit:  Here's what I ended up with.  IN was the insight that got this from 51 queries down to 2!**

```
<?php
// Query for the last 50 orders
$q_orders['orders'] = // SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 50

// Create array of order numbers
foreach($q_orders['orders'] as $order){
    $order_numbers[] = $order['order_number'];
}   

// Query for all the deliveries
$q_deliveries = // SELECT * FROM deliveries WHERE order_number IN ($order_numbers)

// For each order, append the deliveries with the same order_number
$i = 0;
foreach($q_orders['orders'] as $order){

    foreach($q_deliveries as $delivery){

        if($delivery['order_number'] == $order['order_number']){

            $q_orders['orders'][$i]['deliveries'][] = $delivery;

        }

    }

    $i++;

}
```

Comment: Most people on stack can probably help you out with this query, but we *need* more information about the structure of your tables and their relationship (where is the main order_number? Where is the rest of the info?)
If you give me this information I can probably help you out. - If you're using phpmyadmin, a screenshot of the diagram with the necessary tables and relations would be great!

Comment: @Babydead the orders table contains the order_number and the deliveries table contains the id, order_number and status

Comment: @Babydead I added the fields to the questions.  I'm currently querying the orders table to get all the orders which contain the "main order_number" and then for each one querying the deliveries table for each delivery containing that order_number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so from what I could gather, I'll say this:

```
SELECT id, orders.order_number, status
 FROM orders, deliveries
  WHERE orders.order_number = 'ordernumber'
   AND deliveries.order_number = orders.order_number
```

However, I'm quite confused as to why you need the original order number in the first place. You could just select the `deliveries.order_number` right off the bat, couldn't you? like this:

```
SELECT id, order_number, status
     FROM deliveries
      WHERE order_number = 'ordernumber'
```

Now for some PHP magic (I believe this should make the difference, tho I am unable to test it at this time)

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $result_array = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $result_array[] = $row;
    }
?>
```

I'm sorry, I believe I understand your question now.
In that case, no, you cannot use mysql to return a natural php-based multidimensional array. (mysql can't format the results for a specific language)

You will always have to merge the arrays manually if you want to change how the results are sorted.

**Edit: For the multiple orders query**

```
SELECT id, order_number, status
     FROM deliveries
      WHERE order_number IN (2323, 34, 25, 44646, 24, 26)
```

You will want to use `IN`. This means the query will grab any of these order numbers. It's quite easy to fill `IN` with a php array like so:

```
<?php
 $ordernumbers = implode(",", $arrayWithOrderNumbers);
 $query = "SELECT id, order_number, status
     FROM deliveries
      WHERE order_number IN ($ordernumbers)";
?>
```

`IN` is basically short for this: `WHERE order_number = 34 OR order_number = 35 OR order_number = 34`

etc. etc.

Comment: playing with this now - HUGE thanks.  I certainly understand it won't format it, im primarily trying to figure out how to accomplish it with 1 query.

there are a bunch of extra fields in both tables, I just used the about examples to simplify it, thats why i can't query only the deliveries table.

Comment: OH! You mean to find 50 different orders in 1 query? I'm so sorry, let me quickly update my answer with a query  for that one!

Comment: ok so this would be 2 queries right (which is much better than 50!) - one to get the order_numbers and the next to get the deliveries with those order numbers... testing now

Comment: I think it'd help if I knew where you were getting the order_numbers from in the first place. That's probably what's keeping me from seeing the big picture. Anyway, I hope you'll figure it out, I'm off to bed soon (almost 7AM here)

Comment: I query the orders table for the 50 latest orders - and those come with order_numbers

Comment: ohhh right. Ok, so you have them in an array, then. This means you can indeed use my `implode()` example with the `IN()` example.